# MySQL misunderstands the value with the column name

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have executed a simple query

```
select * from content_model_reference cm where cm.element_id = "1.B.1.g";
```

The MySQL gives me this error message

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column '1.B.1.g' in 'where clause'
```

I don't have any idea why this happens on the production server. The above query works fine at local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely with the double-quotes. Some database engines will treat this as a column name rather than a value.

```
SELECT *
  FROM content_model_reference cm 
 WHERE cm.element_id = '1.B.1.g';
```

This should give you what you’re looking for.

Comment: You just saved my life. Thank you.